# Sublime text 3 FTP not working with localhost

Tags: ftp, localhost, sublimetext3, dreamweaver

I am a beginner with sublime text 3. Previous I worked with dream viewer. When I was working with dream viewer, Generally I do keep my project folder in D drive and add new local server in htdoc folder using dream viewer add site option.

Now I need to use sublime text 3 as same I did with dream viewer. I setup a new server using FTP plugin as below

```
// sftp, ftp or ftps
"type": "ftp",

"sync_down_on_open": true,
"sync_same_age": true,

"host": "127.0.0.1",
"user": "root",
"password": "ashan",
//"port": "22",

"remote_path": "/xampp/htdocs/sanka_d/",
```

My remote connection as below (sftp-config.jason)

```
"type": "ftp",

"save_before_upload": true,
"upload_on_save": true,
"sync_down_on_open": false,
"sync_skip_deletes": false,
"sync_same_age": true,
"confirm_downloads": false,
"confirm_sync": true,
"confirm_overwrite_newer": false,

"host": "127.0.0.1",
"user": "root",
"password": "ashan",
//"port": "22",

"remote_path": "/",
```

When I try to connect with remote server it says below error message.

> Connecting to FTP server "127.0.0.1" as "root" ........ failure (Disconnected)

Please help me solve this, Thanks!

Comment: Please help me solve this problem....

Comment: FTP doesn't normally let `root` connect unless you've configured it to, under the theory that if you're doing anything as root you're almost certainly doing something wrong. If you want to fix that you need to configure your FTP server to allow root to connect.

Comment: You say you're using SFTP, but it looks like you configured it to use FTP. They're different protocols. Which one do you actually intend to use?

Comment: Kenster: I need to use FTP.

Comment: OdatNurd: How do I configure My FTP server to allow root to connect.